# How to correctly nest a VLOOKUP and COUNTIF function in Excel?

Tags: excel, nested, vlookup, countif

So in column `B(b2:b1613)` I have a list of peoples initials. In column `E(e2:e1613)` I have the box # they used that day (from 1-14).

I have a separate table that i want to be able to calculate how many times a specific person (column b) uses a specific box number. So my rows are the initial options and the columns are the box numbers 1-14.

So, basically the function needs to say if the value in column `b` is equal to the person's initials (it'll reference column `q2` and so on) and the box number is the same as the column it's currently in (`r` through `ae`) then count it.

I have made A LOT of attempts. This is one I have so far that hasn't worked. Sorry if my attempt was completely horrid - I have researched online and can't seem to find a situation that is similar to mine.

```
=VLOOKUP([@Anest],B2:E1613,COUNTIF(E2:E1613,Table4[[#Headers],[1]]))
```

Anyways, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need `VLOOKUP` - a simple `COUNTIFS` should suffice:

`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$21,[@Anest],$E$2:$E$21,Table1[[#Headers],[1]])`